# Update drag/scroll origin after an update of the data with transition in D3

Tags: javascript, charts, drag-and-drop, d3.js, transition

I work on a chart with dragging, zooming and updates. This mostly works, however, after adding new data, the dragging position does not update.

Steps to reproduce:

- see the demo
- wait some seconds so that some data is added to the graph
- then try dragging the graph to the left or right
- the graph will be pushed back to the beginning and from that point dragging works the way it should

So I guess, when adding new data, I somehow have to update the drag origin. But how? So far I was not able to find any example of that. I also looked at the [code of the dragging functionality of D3](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/behavior/drag.js), but it's still not clear to me. Same thing happens for the zooming, I guess it is the same problem there.

Code and demo can be seen here:
http://jsbin.com/irixag/1/edit

Edit: If it is not clear what I mean, please tell me so that I can rephrase the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I've been sifting through your code and the d3.js source and I've noticed a couple of things.

First, the gist of my solution is to add

```
function update() {
    ...
    if (shiftRight) {
        zoom.x(x); // You're missing this line
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Here's why:

You are initializing the horizontal drag and drop by using the `.x(x)` call on the `d3.behavior.zoom()` object. This looks fine, except this drag & drop handler is not designed for a varying origin.

Basically, when you call `d3.behavior.zoom().x(x)` you are declaring that *right now* the value of `x` is the origin. Now, d3.js stores this value, so even though you are shifting the window right in an animation loop, drag & drops will still honor that original origin.

In the `d3.behavior.zoom` source there are three variables of interest, `x0`, `x1`, and `translate`. `x1` is a reference to the current value of the `x` variable you passed in. `x0` is the copied value of `x` when you initially passed it in. `translate` is the aggregate translation of all your drag+drops combined.

Now, conveniently, calling `zoom.x(x)` resets all three of these variables, which means the translation will only be aggregated against the current origin, and the origin will reflect your shifting window.